# How do I assign multiple colors to the "X" axis in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'd like to make a line graph that looks like this in bokeh:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/X6A049C.png]

How do I set multiple colours for the `X-axis` in bokeh?

I tried to use `p.xaxis.axis_line_color` and `p.xaxis.bounds` but they don't allow me to assign multiple colours to a single axis.

How can I get the desired result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a Bokeh function to do this, but you can draw it yourself.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import LabelSet, ColumnDataSource

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, x_range=(-1.5, 9.5), y_range=(-1.5, 9.5))
p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
p.xaxis.visible = False
p.yaxis.visible = False
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.multi_line(xs=[[0, 3], [3, 6], [6, 9], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], ys=[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 3], [3, 6], [6, 9]], color=['green', 'yellow', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'], line_width=2)
source = ColumnDataSource({'x':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], 'y':[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,], 'text':['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']})
labels = LabelSet(x='x', y='y', text='text', source=source, x_offset=-10, y_offset=-10)
p.add_layout(labels)

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, thank you Jasper! This is a great workaround to achieve the multi-color axis.